# update LastModifiedDate audit field for test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

is there any way to update the LastModifiedDate audit field for test coverage.

Comment: No, there are no way. You could try to do next things:
1) Use Test.loadData;
2) Split logic that you need to cover to avoid using LastModifiedDate as criteria, and cover it separately

Comment: json.deserialize will do the trick